# Create value format with flexible, performant operators

Tags: c++

I would like to ask for a design advice on the following issue:

I have a class that is supposed to represent number data in a database, like this:

```
class Value
{
   ...
};
```

From this class, a number of numeral classes is derived:

```
class Integer : public Value {}; 
class Short   : public Value {};
class Double  : public Value {};
class Integer16 : public Value {};
...
```

The list is bound to grow in the future with more specialized number formats.

Now what I want to do is to create several comparison operators (`<`, `==`, `!=` etc.) in a way that they can be extended easily to incorporate new number formats. The operators should be able to compare numbers of different formats (like `Double` and `Integer16`).

Also, I want to design the subclasses in a way that those comparisons can be done very fast. As far as I can tell this means I have to avoid unnecessary conversions. Basically I have multiple large lists of numbers

```
Integer a[10000]; Double b[2000]; Integer16 c[2333]; ...
```

Every frame a number of pairs is generated from this set and for every pair the comparison operator is supposed to be called. Like this:

```
operator<( a[100]m, b[17 );
```

My concern is now how I can design the classes and the comparison operators so that they are flexible and the comparison is fast.

My first idea was to separate the numbers into floating points and integrals and promote the values of all the derived types to the largest parent type:

```
class FloatingPoint : public Value { float64_t val; };
class Integral      : public Value { int64_t  val; };
```

That means for example an `Integer16` would convert its value to an `int64_t` internally.

Then I would just have to create optimized comparison operators for `(float64_t, float64_t)`, `(float64_t, int64_t)`, `(int64_t, float64_t)`, `(int64_t, int64_t)`. Also between numbers of the same types the operators would not have to do any type checking. However, converting everything to the most powerful type may be slow for certain cpus with arithmetic comparisons, right?

Do you have any better proposals how to implement this? Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: First you say you want to avoid conversions to make it fast and then you say to solve the problem of conversions being neccesarry sometimes you want to do to conversion always... i cannot really follow that argumentation.

Comment: The point is that if I want to compare two numbers of different types then conversion is theoretically mandatory. However, I would prefer if I could make this conversion only once (when the numbers are initialized) and not every time I call the comparison operators. I would also like to avoid type checking every time I call the operators. Therefore my idea is to have all the type variations use the same format internally (int64_t, float64_t) and then compare only the internal values.

Comment: I believe that the cost of a conversion taking place when comparing e.g. a `double` with an `int` is zero. On the other hand, the price to store all 16/32 bit values in 64 bits is enormous. Are you sure that you need anything else than the build-in operators? All this looks like a premature optimization to me

Comment: As stated before, the default case is that every frame I get a number of pairs of type ( Value, Value ) for comparison and I don't know the type of both values in advance. So I would have to check both types, then make a large switch statement that selects the right operator for the combination at hand. Also our policy doesn't allow implicit conversions.

Comment: sorry I dont get it. Why isnt `<` the "right operator for the combination at hand"?

Comment: Say I write a < for the generic combination ( Value&, Value& ). Then I would have to check for the dynamic type of both entries and cast both of them to their dynamic type. Then I would have to write code paths for every possible type combination so the right comparison is performed. I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Are the numbers coming in as strings or as binary data?  At what point do you know the type? Maybe put out a use case.

Comment: I suggest looking at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant.html